# Run programs installed by Pip in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, python3

As a newbie I try to learn new things everyday, especially when installing: apt, snap, flatpack, appimage, etc.
Yesterday I found pip: Python Package Installer, but couldn't get it to work.
To test pip I tried a funny little terminal program: Doge.
I use Ubuntu 20.04, it's Python 3 only, and has no Python 2 support.

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install doge
$ pip3 list
```

So Doge 3.5.0 is listed. But how do I run the program?

The Doge program is not important, I can download it with wget and it works.
The important qestion is: how do I run something installed by pip?

Comment: The [project page](https://pypi.org/project/doge/) says that you should have an executable `doge`, so you should run `doge` as a terminal command. If that doesn't work, does `which doge` turn up anything?

Answer (score 2):

After some help I found that I missed a line in the beginning of the installation. The correct way is:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-setuptools
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install doge
$ pip3 list
```

If I  wasn't such a noob I would have used **which** to begin. It gave:

/usr/local/bin

so this also worked:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ./doge
```

Comment: Actually in your case `hash -r` in Bash would have made any such path also known. But which works, of course. If you did `pip install --user` you would have to look in `~/.local/bin`. This is what I prefer, because anything that isn't really packaged feels like a sore spot on a shiny new installation ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a matter of finding "[Where does pip install its packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages)".

Considering the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309460/1505369) it's possible to use `pip show <Package name>` to find the location (as "Location").

For me it seems to be `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/<Package name>`.

If one would like to use packages just as regular commends I would consider modifying the `PATH` variable.